# What is the significance of μέρει in Colossians 2:16?

Tags: greek, grammar, colossians

> Μὴ οὖν τις ὑμᾶς κρινέτω ἐν βρώσει καὶ ἐν πόσει ἢ ἐν μέρει ἑορτῆς ἢ νεομηνίας ἢ σαββάτων, <sup>NA27</sup>

The list of items in which not to allow yourselves to be judged is delimited by ἐν: «ἐν βρώσει...ἐν πόσει...ἐν μέρει ἑορτῆς ἢ...»

I can’t clarify in my mind what the significance μέρει brings to the text. ἐν  μέρει is nearly universally translated as “in regard to,” but isn’t “regard to” implied in the other instances of ἐν? What is distinct and different in the third ἐν that it requires μέρει, and what does μέρει add that isn’t implied by the other instances of ἐν?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shift is necessary to avoid the clash of an 'in of', or, it is necessary for the shift from 'to/in' (dative) to 'of' (genetive) in the list of items.

Thus St. Paul uses 'in *the way/area/respect* of.'— ἐν μέρει to change from 'as to food or drink' to 'in the area of'.

You'll notice that the kinds of things we are not to allow ourselves to be judged by, which follow *ἐν μέρει* are in the *genetive*: *of* festival days, *of* new moons, *of* new Sabbaths.

Notice the distinct sections of the sentence, and where a slight shift takes place:

> Μὴ οὖν τις ὑμᾶς κρινέτω
>
> Let no one judge you therefore

---

> ἐν βρώσει καὶ ἐν πόσει
>
> *in* food **and** in drink

---

> ἢ ἐν μέρει ἑορτῆς [shift takes place here]
>
> **or** in the area *of* a feast

---

> ἢ νεομηνίας
>
> **or** *of* a new moon

---

> ἢ σαββάτων
>
> **or** *of* Sabbaths

Or, put another way, St. Paul puts together, as we often do, 'food and drink' as a kind of 'genre' of its own. Hence the simple 'and'.